# xargs multiple replacement string

Tags: shell, curl, printf, xargs

I want to use curl to make a bunch of http requests in parallel for some performance testing of a server.

The request requires a MAC address, which I would like to count upwards in the following way.

```
00:00:00:00:AA:BB
             ^  ^
             |  \___ count from 00 to ff (hex)
             \______ count from 00 to ff (hex)
```

BB shall overflow to AA when it is getting larger than 0xFF

What I got so far is, incrementing BB and send the request in a parallel way.

```
printf "%02x\n" {0..255} | xargs -I{} -P4 -- \
    curl -s \
    http://nginx/api/onboard/01:02:03:04:00:{}
```

This works fine, but I need to request more than 256 times.

xargs is BusyBox v1.31.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It is actually not xargs related as I thought first.

```
printf "%04x\n" {0..1000} | \
sed -r 's/([[:xdigit:]]{2})([[:xdigit:]]{2})/\1:\2/g' | \
xargs -I{} -P4 -- \
curl -k -s \
    https://nginx/api/onboard/21:12:12:12:{}
```

I'm creating the needed part of the MAC with a combination of printf and sed. There is probably a better way but it solves my problem.